# Firebase database not showing nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have connected to my database and I know there is a connection there because when I select authentication and add a user it works but when I try to access the realtime database this is what I see:

[image: Firebase database image]

On all the tutorials I watch a node saying null comes up by default. Also  I cannot dismiss the warning